# How can use two array lists in one for loop?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have to enter some data to database, see my code. I am facing problem on two times execute Insert Query.
So I want one for loop that contain both Strings and ArrayList.

```
public static ArrayList<String> ApplicationPackageList  = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> ApplicationList        = new ArrayList<String>();
.
.
.
for (String r : ApplicationPackageList ) {

                DB.insertStmt.bindString(1, URLDecoder.decode(r));
                DB.insertStmt.executeInsert();
            }

for (String s : ApplicationList) {

                // DB.insertStmt.bindString(1, URLDecoder.decode(r));
                DB.insertStmt.bindString(2, URLDecoder.decode(s));
                DB.insertStmt.executeInsert();

            }
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this ? How do you intend to assemble the strings of the two lists together ? Are they of the same size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<ApplicationList.size() && i< ApplicationPackageList .size(); i++){
  DB.insertStmt.bindString(1, URLDecoder.decode(ApplicationList.get(i)));  
  DB.insertStmt.bindString(2, URLDecoder.decode(ApplicationPackageList.get(i)));
  DB.insertStmt.executeInsert(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... its working.. but only up to "9" iteration. Application Name & Package Name does not print similar in database after 1oth iteration. Any suggestion??

Comment: @Nimit the work of this loops is to run until either of ApplicationList or AppicationPackageList exhaust. You can add a `System.out.println("i: "+i+", applist: "+URLDecoder.decode(ApplicationList.get(i))+", appPkgList: "+ URLDecoder.decode(ApplicationPackageList.get(i)));` after execute insert to see what's going (and how many) into DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
List newList  - new ArrayList();
newLIst.addAll(ApplicationList);
newLIst.addAll(ApplicationPackageList );
```

now iterate `newList`, but it wouldn't make any *positive* impact on performance,